# when converting charter in to numeric the higher value data becomes Na

Tags: r, dplyr

I have tried to convert the total column in to numeric  data$total<-as.numeric(data$total) using this code it is working fine for small number when it comes to big("7,29,842" )it becomes na

So kindly share your thoughts and any idea would be appreciated

sample data

```
structure(list(revenue = c("20", "1.46", "52", "1.5", "32.59", 
"11.31", "0.37", "0.65", "0", "5.58", "7,29,842", "58", "8.7", 
"0.32", "113", "0.84", "24", "34.8", "0.36", "2.85", "0", "34.32", 
"0")), row.names = c(NA, -23L), class = "data.frame")
    
1    20.00
2     1.46
3    52.00
4     1.50
5    32.59
6    11.31
7     0.37
8     0.65
9     0.00
10    5.58
11      NA
12   58.00
13    8.70
14    0.32
15  113.00
16    0.84
17   24.00
18   34.80
19    0.36
20    2.85
21    0.00
22   34.32
23    0.00
```

Comment: Remove the commas from your "big" numbers before conversion.

Comment: Because your element number 11 has a decimal coma instead of period.

Comment: `readr::parse_number()` handles most number formats well "out of the box"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
as.numeric(gsub(",","",df$revenue))
```

Output:

```
[1]     20.00      1.46     52.00      1.50     32.59     11.31      0.37      0.65      0.00
[10]      5.58 729842.00     58.00      8.70      0.32    113.00      0.84     24.00     34.80
[19]      0.36      2.85      0.00     34.32      0.00
```